# Using Symbols from Feature Layer for Graphics Layer in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

I have a feature layer being drawn from a map service. I have a graphics layer that is the result of a query (happens to be on the same feature layer). I wish to apply the same symbols from the Feature Layer to the new graphics layer produced by the query but have had no such luck.  Relevant code bellow:

```
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(http://........);

function handleQuery(queryRslt) { 
    var queryGraphicsArray = queryRslt.features;
    var featureLayerSymbol = featureLayer.renderer.getSymbol(); 
    for (var i = 0 ; i < queryGraphicsArray.length ; i ++) { 
        queryGraphicsArray[i].symbol = featureLayerSymbol;
        map.graphics.add(queryGraphicsArray[i]);
}
```

I can confirm that the query is in fact functioning properly. I can also confirm that the symbol appears to being changed using console.log and debugging tool. However nothing is added to the map.

The symbol is a picture symbol added inside of arcMap before publishing to AGS. It is a ping image.

Any thoughts as to where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need to create a new graphic layer because you can also filter the existing feature layer with the following code:

```
featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression(<<your expression>>);
```

Comment: I had a feeling there would be a much simpler method. Sometimes I get lost navigating the api documentation. 

Question: The way I would like this to work is that the user clicks button one, it shows relevant data of the Feature Layer, button two would essentially do the same but with a different query. Would you refresh() the layer on the event. Or is there another method to ensure the  new definition query gets applied to the map?

Comment: No need to do anything, setDefinition() expression automatically is reflected on the map.